# How to use Rest Service while using Spring Boot & Spring Data Jpa

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-tool-suite

Im working on a spring boot application for rest service with using spring data jpa. I followed instructors and read much answers but I couldn't fix my rest service.

Here is `application.class`

```
package tr.kasim.Application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("tr.kasim.Dao")
@EntityScan("tr.kasim.Model")
@ComponentScan({"tr.kasim.Service", "tr.kasim.Application" })
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

Here is `restcontroller.class

```
package tr.kasim.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import tr.kasim.Service.PersonelService;
import tr.kasim.Model.Personel;


@RestController
public class STRestController {

@Autowired
public PersonelService personelService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/personels", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Personel>> getPersonels(){
    List<Personel> personels = personelService.findAll();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(personels);
}

}
```

`

Here is Service.class`

```
package tr.kasim.Service;

 import java.util.List;

import tr.kasim.Model.Personel;

public interface PersonelService {

List<Personel> findAll();
}
```

`

Here is ServiceImplemantion.class

```
package tr.kasim.Service;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import tr.kasim.Dao.PersonelDao;
import tr.kasim.Model.Personel;

@Service
public class PersonelServiceImpl implements PersonelService {

@Autowired
private PersonelDao personelDao;

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Personel> findAll() {

    return personelDao.findAll();
}

}
```

Here is Dao.class

```
    package tr.kasim.Dao;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import tr.kasim.Model.Personel;

@Repository
public interface PersonelDao extends JpaRepository<Personel, Long> {

List<Personel> findAll();
}
```

Lastly here is my application.properties

```
#MySql Connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exampleproject?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#Jpa/Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#Logging
logging.file=staffTracking.log
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
```

Im not sure about componentScan. When I read answers I discovered someone mentioned about it but I tried and I got still nothing. Please show me where I failed. Best Regards.

I updated Application.class, now I can deploying project but rest service not working still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you try `ComponentScan`? The issue here seems that you have a package structure like this:

```
tr.kasim.Application
  - Application.java
tr.kasim.Service
  - PersonelService.java
  - PersonelServiceImpl.java
tr.kasim.Dao
 - PersonelDao.java
```

Now since, the `mainClass` is in `tr.kasim.Application` it would scan for bean definitions inside that package (or a sub-package in `tr.kasim.Application`). So,

- either you move the `mainClass` out to a parent-package like `tr.kasim`, or
- use `@ComponentScan({ "tr.kasim.Dao", "tr.kasim.Service", "tr.kasim.Application" })` and so on.

-- Update --

Based on the discussion so far, I'd suggest taking the first option as that reduces the effort to manually enable scan for entity, repository, etc.

Comment: Hello Sinbad90 , firstly thank you for your answer. But I tried this before and took that error: 

Field personelDao in tr.kasim.Service.PersonelServiceImpl required a bean of type 'tr.kasim.Dao.PersonelDao' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'tr.kasim.Dao.PersonelDao' in your configuration.

Comment: have you tried pass the package name `tr.kasim.Dao` to `@EnableJpaRepositories`?

Comment: When I wrote here @EnableJpaResositories("tr.kasim.Dao") I took this error: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personelServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personelDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personelDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class tr.kasim.Model.Personel

Comment: Your model class `Personel` might be missing `@Entity`, due to which it is not recognised as a managed type. Can you confirm this, or share the code for the model class?

Comment: Unfortunately, I checked it before and  my model classes has @Entity annotation..

Comment: pls share the code for the model class, in fact can you pls update all the code with changes made so far... need to know what you have and what might be missing

Comment: chances are you might need `@EntityScan("tr.kasim.Model")`

Comment: Hello again and thank you, @EntityScan("tr.kasim.Model") worked and project deployed but still rest api does not working when I tried to reach "localhost:8080/api/personels" . Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: the error I got at browser: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Apr 28 15:55:52 EET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: okay I totally missed the controller class in my answer; pls add `tr.kasim.Controller` to the `@ComponentScan`... right now your controller class is not getting picked up

Comment: It's totally working right now. You helped me really so much. Thank you! @Sindbad90

Comment: Great! Just a suggestion: keep your main class in a package that's at a higher level than all other beans. Reduces effort.

Comment: Sure! I did. Thank you again.