# Spring Boot - Autowiring null inside abstract class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, abstract-class, autowired

I have below classes.

```
public interface Operation
public abstract class AbstractOperation  implements Operation
public class Operation extends AbstractOperation
```

Class Operation

```
public interface Operation {
     GenericClientResponse validateCustomerId();
```

Class AbstractOperation

```
public abstract class AbstractOperation  implements Operation {

    protected GenericClientRequest buildClientValidationRequest() {
        return new GenericClientRequest();
    }
```

In Operation class there are properties autowired.

```
public class Operation extends AbstractOperation {
    @Autowired
    UserAccountsRepository userAccountsRepository; // not autowiring
    @Autowired
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder; // not autowiring
```

But none of these properties are autowired. They are null at run time.
But if i autowire these in my service class autowiring is successfully done.

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class TransactionServiceImpl implements TransactionService {

          @Autowired
          UserAccountsRepository userAccountsRepository; // Autowires successfully.
```

Please find repository class below.

```
public interface UserAccountsRepository extends 
             JpaRepository<UserAccountsEntity, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT account FROM UserAccountsEntity account where 
                 account.accountNo = :acc")
    UserAccountsEntity getAccountByAccNo(@Param("acc") String userId);
```

In my code i keep a map of Operation classes and get related operation class according to a key.

```
 operationMap.put("test_op1", new Operation());
 operationMap.put("test_op2", new Operation2());
```

Then i call this to get correct operation

```
Optional.ofNullable(operationMap.get("test_op1"));
```

Now i undestands that creating new instance is causing null autowiring. How i get new object without new key word?

Comment: Could you please add a few details to your code: 1. packages of all the classes you've shown and the `main` boot class. 2. Annotation on the class `Operation`.

Comment: Can you show how you instantiate `Operation`?

Comment: Please refer my updated question @priyank-sriv

Comment: Please refer my updated question @HasanCanSaral

Comment: There's no answer to my question in your update @bynu022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably instantiating `Operation` with `new` as follows:

```
Operation operation = new Operation(...);
```

This is making your `Operation` instance non-Spring managed. Hence, since Spring doesn't know about your instance, it cannot autowire your dependencies.

If you do like:

```
@Component
public class Operation {
...
}
```

you will get your dependencies autowired correctly. If you really need to instantiate `Operation` yourself and keep the autowired dependencies, you'll need to go for `Configurable`. See a couple of references:

- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/spring-configurable-magic.html
- http://olivergierke.de/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/

Comment: Yes you are correct. I'm creating new instance to get related operation from a map.Please refer my updated question

Comment: That's the point. This answers your question. Spring cannot autowire the bean to the instances you create with new. Either mark them as `@Component` (without `new`) and autowire `Operation` itself when you need it, or use `@Configurable`.

Comment: Did you read my answer? There's reference to what you need to do: `@Configurable`. But it's a pretty costly thing to do, and it's not just adding `@Configurable`. Please refer to the links.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of possibilities, based on what you've shared:

1. The package structure is not correct - if the class `Operation` isn't in the same package (or a sub-package) as the `main` class, the component scan may pick your class. 
   Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884907/how-to-use-rest-service-while-using-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa/55887110#55887110) answer to make sure you've implemented the package structure correctly.
2. You may be missing a Spring annotation on the class `Operation`, such as `@Component` or `@Service`. Or you may be instantiating the class manually in you code, outside of the Spring application context. Please verify that you're creating the bean properly.

In case you're trying to create the bean manually, you should do it [using](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-bean-annotation-with-example.html) `@Bean` in a configuration class.